# Count date mismatches between two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, mismatch

I have two columns of date of birth (in the data frame) for each person in my Dataset. I want R to count the times when the values in both columns are not the same. That means counting the number of people for whom two birth date columns are not the same.

I tried to create a loop to get a vector (it's length = number of people in the dataset) when 1 = unequal dates of birth.

```
x=rep(0,4092)
  for (i in length(x)){
    if(mydata$datebirth1[i]== (mydata$datebirth2[i]){x[i]=FALSE}
    else{x[i]=TRUE}
  } 
x
```

Note that I have some  NA values in the 2 columns

Comment: Hey, please add some code showing what you have done so far and the database table structure so it's easier to help you.

Comment: thank you, i added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you create a new column of 1s and 0s, where 1 means the two dates don't match.

```
df <- transform(df, c= ifelse(a==b, 0, 1))
```

Then you can easily apply `sum` to the column you've created:

```
sum(df$c)
```

For the future, please consider providing the code of the solutions you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with dplyr:

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble::tibble(one = c(1L:6L),
               two = c(1L, 2L, 4L:7L)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(same = one == two)

A tibble: 6 x 3
    one   two same 
  <int> <int> <lgl>
1     1     1 TRUE 
2     2     2 TRUE 
3     3     4 FALSE
4     4     5 FALSE
5     5     6 FALSE
6     6     7 FALSE
```

one and two simulate your date columns. The format of the data does not matter

Comment: and if i want the third column to be the result of subtraction between one and two?